# VS2013 Profiler: location of collected data

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2013, profiling

On my machine I two drives: C(128GB SSD) and D( 1Tb HardDisk). In VS2013 I'm analysing the memory usage of an application I've developed. I had installed VS in C and run one of those memory usage analysis from Analysis>Performance and Diagnostics>Memory Ussage. All fine here.

My problem is that I'm short of space in C and I can't run long analysis. Therefore, I decided to uninstall VS from C and install it in D hoping that all this profiling info was going to be (temporarily, i.e. the file created and updated while running the analysis) stored somewhere in D:\Visual Studio\ . However, this is not the case. It's still stored somewhere in C, and therefore I still have the same problem as before. Is there a whay to modify this default location?

Comment: It is stored in your TEMP directory.  Easy to put that directory somewhere else albeit that this defeats the usefulness of the SSD somewhat.  If you don't know how then ask at superuser.com

Comment: Yes, I found several log files related to this profiling analysis in "C:\Users\<my username>\AppData\Local\Temp", but they're in the range of 100-1000Kb in size.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with the litter you found back, VS is awfully sloppy, everything to do with how much space is left on the drive.

Comment: Thanks! Changing the location of the TEMP directory solved my issue. You may want to write it as a short answer...

Comment: I'm fairly sure you know everything you need to write your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by [Hans Passat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant), I just needed to change the location of my TEMP directory. The first answer in this [link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/change-location-of-temp-files-folder-to-another/19f13330-dde1-404c-aa27-a76c0b450818) describes how to do it. After following those 5 steps a system restart is required.